Do the two components of Whitehead link bound disjoint smoothly embedded disks in the four ball?
I encounter this problem when reading Kauffman's book "On knots". A way to construct slice disks for knots is proposed, as follows, given a knot $K$ in $S^3$, with a spanning surface $F,\partial F=K,$ assume the genus of $F$ is $g$, if we can find $g$ essential simple closed curves in $F$, which generate a subgroup of $H_1(F)$ of rank $g$, all of whom are slice knots, further assuming that the Seifert form restricted to these $g$ curves vanishes, then we can surgery on these $g$ curves along their slice disks to obtain a slice disk for $K$.
In such a construction, the possible intersections between different slice disks confuse me. My question is that, given $K_1$ and $K_2$ slice and $lk(K_1,K_2)=0,$ is it possible to obtain slice disks $\hat{D}_1, \hat{D}_2$ of $K_1,K_2$ such that $\hat{D}_1\cap \hat{D}_2=\emptyset$? If it is so, how to operate? If not, what is the counter example?
There is an explanation about linking number between knots in terms of the chains they bound in $D^4$, assume $K_1, K_2$ are disjoint oriented knots in $S^3=\partial D^4,$ which bound smoothly properly embedded disks $D_1,D_2$ in the oriented four ball $D^4$ respectively. When $D_1,D_2$ are given orientations compatible with their boundaries $K_1,K_2,$ and $S^3$ has the orientation induced from $D^4,$ it is known that $lk(K_1,K_2)=\# D_1\cap D_2,$ where $\#D_1\cap D_2$ is the algebraic intersection number between $D_1$ and $D_2.$ For example, consult [enter link description here][1].
Give a look at a simplest example, the Whitehead link $L=K_1\cup K_2,$ where $K_1$ and $K_2$ are both trivial knots, do $K_1$ and $K_2$ bound disjoint smoothly embedded disks in $D^4$?
Appreciation to any comment!
